Quarto document output
After spending several days troubleshooting, I managed to get my code working in R on my work computer. I now have to render in quarto . However, Quarto isn't functioning as expected; it fails to render the PDF with the output file, and unfortunately, I don’t have access to the terminal on the work laptop so I must work on R console opening the quarto document there.  Is there any way anyone could guide me on how to troubleshoot this issue further? I would greatly appreciate any insights or recommendations you may have. I am attaching the rendered quarto document which shows my code and the actual script that gave me all the right answers and graphs. Additionally , I attach my assignment. Thank you very much to anyone reading this. Gaia enter image description here here is my code
setwd("C:/Users/gaia.streparola/Desktop")getwd()  # Verify the working directory
install.packages("viridis")
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(stringr)
library(writexl)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(viridis)
library(ggrepel)

Data_STAT <- read_excel("DATA_QUARTO2.xlsx")
str(Data_STAT)  # View dataset structure

Data_STAT <- Data_STAT %>%rename(
  Cybercrimes = Acts against computer systems,
  Drug Offenses = Unlawful acts involving controlled drugs or precursors,
  Criminal Organization = Participation in an organized criminal group
)
participation_table <- Data_STAT %>%select(Country, Criminal Organization) %>%
  arrange(desc(Criminal Organization)) %>%
  mutate(Normalized_Value = (Criminal Organization - min(Criminal Organization, na.rm = TRUE)) /(max(Criminal Organization, na.rm = TRUE) - min(Criminal Organization, na.rm = TRUE))
)

kbl(participation_table, format = "html") %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = FALSE) %>%
  column_spec(1, bold = TRUE, border_right = TRUE, width = "20em") %>%column_spec(2, width = "20em") %>%
  column_spec(3, width = "20em") %>%
  row_spec(0, bold = TRUE, color = "white", background = "darkgrey") %>%
  row_spec(1:nrow(participation_table), background = "#FFF9C4")

highest_participation_country <- participation_table %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  pull(Country)
cat("Country with the Highest Participation in Criminal Organization:", highest_participation_country)

Data_STAT$Robbery <- as.numeric(Data_STAT$Robbery)
Data_STAT$Drug Offenses <- as.numeric(Data_STAT$Drug Offenses)
country_colors <- c("Finland" = "#7FFFDD", "Malta" = "#0000FF", "Slovenia" = "#66CDAA","Lithuania" = "#8B7D6B", "Czechia" = "#FFD39B", "Bulgaria" = "#BF3EFF","Italy" = "#C1FFC1", "Germany" = "#838B83", "Croatia" = "#CD5555","Austria" = "#8B864E", "Albania" = "#CD8C95", "Romania" = "#9370DB","Greece" = "#DDA0DD", "Spain" = "#CDCD00")

ggplot(Data_STAT, aes(x = Robbery,y = Drug Offenses,label = Country)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Country, fill = Country), size = 3, alpha = 0.8, shape = 21) +
  geom_text_repel(size = 3, box.padding = 0.35, point.padding = 0.3,segment.size = 0.25, min.segment.length = 0.1, max.overlaps = 10) +
labs(title = "Relationship between Robbery and Drug Offenses by Country",x = "Robbery Rate (per 100,000 People)",y = "Drug Offenses Rate (per 100,000 People)") +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 15) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12, angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    legend.position = "none",plot.margin = unit(c(2, 2, 2, 2), "cm")  # Increase plot margins) +
    xlim(0, max(Data_STAT$Robbery, na.rm = TRUE) * 1.2) +
    ylim(0, 500) +  # Set y-axis limit explicitly to 500
    scale_color_manual(values = country_colors) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = country_colors)
avg_crime_data <- Data_STAT %>%
  summarise(across(Robbery:Overall_Offences, mean, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Overall_Offences, 
    names_to = "Crime_Type", 
    values_to = "Average_Rate"
  )

pastel_colors <- c("#FFB3BA", "#FFDFBA", "#FFFFBA", "#BAFFC9", "#BAE1FF","#FFBAE1", "#B0E0E6", "#DDA0DD")
ggplot(
  avg_crime_data, 
  aes(
    x = Crime_Type, 
    y = Average_Rate, 
    fill = Crime_Type
  )
) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_fill_manual(values = pastel_colors) +
labs(
  title = "Average Crime Rates by Category", 
  x = "Crime Type", 
  y = "Average Rate"
) +
theme_minimal() +
theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
  plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold")
)

world_map <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
data_long <- pivot_longer(
  Data_STAT, 
  cols = c(Intentional homicide, Serious assault, Robbery),
  names_to = "Crime_Type", 
  values_to = "Rate"
)
filtered_world_map <- world_map %>%
  filter(name %in% Data_STAT$Country)
merged_data <- filtered_world_map %>%
  left_join(data_long, by = c("name" = "Country"))
ggplot(
  data = merged_data) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Rate), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(
    colors = c("#FF9999", "#FFCC99", "#99CCFF", "#CC99FF"), name = "Crime Rate", na.value = "grey"
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Crime Rates by Country in Europe", 
    subtitle = "Intentional Homicide, Serious Assault, and Robbery"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~ Crime_Type) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "right",
    plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 16, hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 12, hjust = 0.5),
    strip.text = element_text(face = "bold", size = 12)
  )

I tried to render the pdf from R without success. All I get is this. Printed code chunks. I can’t work with my personal lap``top unfortunately and I normally render the pdf  with my terminal

Can you make PDFs using standard Quarto document templates?  Can you knit Rmd documents?

The code in the question looks like a regular R script.  You can include code for a quarto document by using four backticks at the start and end of the code block.  Then the triple backticks for code chunks inside the block will render just fine.
